# React Router dynamic url rendering over static url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a path="/:user" but it also renders in other static pages like /register and /login because react-router thinks it is also a "username". How can I fix this without changing the pathnames of any of my routers? ie making a white list if that's possible?

***Wanted behavior:***

/1 -> renders 'hi user 1' page

/login -> renders login page

/register -> renders register page

***Happening behavior:***

/1 -> renders 'hi user 1' page

/login -> renders login and 'hi user login' page

/register -> renders register and 'hi user register' page

***My code***

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route exact path="/:user" component={User} />
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It's mostly a case of missing `exact` on your route paths, please add your router logic in the description

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, but I tried playing around with the exact keyword already. Doesn't fix it :|

Comment: Then please wrap Switch like `<Switch> <Router></Router> </Switch>`

Comment: It gives me this error Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Comment: sry, i meant to say wrap the Route with Switch like this `<Switch> <Route></Switch>`. You could create a codesandbox to better help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using switch. It will stop looking for matches and render the first matched Route. Here's a link to the documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

```js
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
          <Route exact path="/:user" component={User} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, but when I try this my pages just go blank and renders nothing.

Comment: @Jpark9061 could you share error which you see in browser console?

Comment: oh wait haha nevermind it worked, I accidentally put the switch key before <App /> which was why it wasn't working. I copy pasted your code and it works! Thank you so much :)